# Downsize 1080p video to 720p

Tags: video, conversion, 1080p

I have a 1080p HD video and I want to reduce its size by converting it to 720p. I know there are software programs capable of doing this(Handbrake, Vidcoder, FFmpeg, etc.) but instead of the file size getting smaller it got *larger*.

I would like to ask for software programs that can convert the video to 720p without increasing its file size and if possible, instructions on how to use the particular software.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact details of what tool you used and what settings you had set when you used it.

Comment: We don't deal with software recommendation questions here; they tend to attract spam and go out of date quickly. You might be able to ask at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com if you're really specific about what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with the format, and entirely to do with the bitrate.
A 720p file could be roughly half the bitrate of a 1080p file and have a similar quality (in terms of compression artefacts). So when you reencode to 720p make sure you reduce the bitrate. Otherwise the file will be the same file size, or possibly bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the output format selected.

Try using [MPEG-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4) as the output video format. It achieves a high compression ratio and delivers a compact file size with the lower data rate, however, quality of a level.

Comment: I have already done that. The size of my source file was 181MB(MP4 1080p) and when converted it became 218MB(MP4 720p) both with the same video and audio codecs.